# Click event on cloned element not working despite $(document).on('click', '.foo', function) method

Tags: html, jquery, append, click

I have the following div

```
<div class = 'step'></div>
```

attached to a `click()` event which adds a class to `.step` if it doesn't have it and vice versa:

```
$(".step").click(function(){
  if ($(this).hasClass('stepLit')) {
    $(this).removeClass('stepLit')
  } else {
    $(this).addClass('stepLit')
  }
})
```

I clone the div like so:

```
var step = $(".step").clone()
```

and append it:

```
$(step).appendTo('#foo')
```

Now, if I want to attach a click event to all existing and dynamically generated HTML elements with class `'.step'`, I have to use the `.on` method thus:

```
$(document).on('click', '.step', function(){...})
```

but the event (adding/removing lit class) still doesn't occur when I click my cloned + appended element. Does it have something to do with the fact that the `this` keyword in my click function now doesn't refer to the div which is clicked, but rather the document?

Comment: This should work, although it'll create multiple elements, since `$('.step')` will return a collection. Please create a full working example.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a demo for you, see if this works for you.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.step', function(){
  if ($(this).hasClass('stepLit')) {
    $(this).removeClass('stepLit');
    $(this).find('span').text('step');
  } else {
    $(this).addClass('stepLit');
    $(this).find('span').text('stepLit');
  }
});



$(document).on('click', '.clone', function(){
  console.clear();
  let $step = $(".step:first").clone()
  console.log($step);
  $step.appendTo("#foo");
});
```

```css
div{
  height: 50px;
}

.step{
  background: aquamarine;
}

.stepLit{
  background: bisque;
}

#foo{
  background: burlywood;
  margin: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='step'>
  <span>step</span><br>
  <button class="clone">Clone</button>
</div>

<div id="foo"></div>
```